Empty logs когда использую model.fit()
Ошибка во время тренировки модели
Здравствуйте! Писал код для создания и тренировки модели, столкнулся с проблемой во время ее тренировки.
Сама ошибка:
"Unexpected result of `train_function` "
ValueError: Unexpected result of `train_function` (Empty logs). Please use `Model.compile(..., run_eagerly=True)`, or `tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)` for more information of where went wrong, or file a issue/bug to `tf.keras`.

Помогите разобраться пожалуйста, буду премного благодарен, голова уже болит от попыток решения этой проблемы
Вот код создания и тренировки модели:
import tensorflow as tf


def create_model():
    """
    Создание модели для задачи регрессии.
    """
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(224, 224, 3)),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)  # Выходной слой для предсказания числового значения
    ])

    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')
    return model


def train_model(model, train_generator, epochs, steps_per_epoch):
    """
    Обучение модели.
    """
    model.fit(train_generator, epochs=epochs, steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch)


Первая же ссылка в гугле по этой ошибке даёт случай, когда в модели предполагается на входе RGB (3 значения), а в реальности подаётся Grayscale (1 канал). Вы что на вход подаёте? Также могут быть какие-то проблемы с генератором данных.

Please use run_eagerly=True for more information of where went wrong Сделайте, как указано в сообщении, и возможно, получите более подробную информацию об ошибке.
